# How can I make the output more elegant when I splitting the data.frame in the list?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have data.frame objects in the list, I intend to split them by its last column. However, I tried to use split function to do this task, and now each data.frame has two subset accordingly. My next attempt is to filter out only sub data.frame from each by its names, while rest of the data.frame can be returned by function, more precisely, to filter out saved data.frame from nested list as returned output. Can anyone help me how to facilitate the this task more comfortable way ? which possible action I might to do? Any way to make the output well represented ? Thanks in advance

quick reproducible example:

```
dfList <- list(hola= data.frame( start=seq(1, by=4, len=15), to=seq(3, by=4, len=15), value=sample(30, 15)),
               boo = data.frame( start=seq(3, by=7, len=20), to=seq(6, by=7, len=20), value=sample(30, 20)),
               meh = data.frame( start=seq(4, by=8, len=25), to=seq(7, by=8, len=25), value=sample(30, 25)))
```

I attempt to implement the function as follow:

```
splitMe <- function(list, ...) {
  # check input
  rslt <- lapply(list, function(x) {
    out <- split(x, ifelse(x$value >= 10, "save", "discard"))
    # intend to filter out discard data.frame and export it as csv file 
    # How Can I make this happen
    # while I intend to only return save data.frame from each as output of splitMe
  })
}
```

Regarding the skeleton of my function, how can I make it complete? How can I get my desired output more efficiently? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: It looks fine to me, perhaps you can change `ifelse` to `lapply(dfList, function(x) setNames(split(x, x$value >=10), c('discard', 'save')))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function:

```
splitMe <- function(list, filename, path, threshold...) {
  out <- lapply(list, subset, value>=threshold)
  csv <- lapply(list, subset, value<threshold)
  mapply(function(x, y) write.csv(x, paste0(path, filename, "_", y, ".csv")), csv, c(1:length(list)))
  return(out)
  }
```

You put in your list and strings in form of "testfile" for `filename` and "C:/DiscardedData/" as `path`.

This way your discarded data will be saved as testfile_1.csv, testfile_2.csv and so on.

Edit: Put in a threshold so its more dynamic. Just define your threshold value in the function call.

Another edit: To use the function, just call something like `ouput <- splitMe(dfList, filename = "discarded", path = "yourpath", threshold = 10)` and insert your path as `yourpath`.

Comment: Well, you can use something like `split <- lapply(list, function(x) split(x, ifelse(x$value >= threshold, 1, 2))) instead, but that would again leave you with nested lists of two data.frames inside your list, which you would then need to break again, probably using another apply-construct. As I see it, the use of two lapply-calls is the easiest.

Comment: instead of using lapply twice in function, any chance to tighten up splitting data.frame more elegantly ? Thanks

Comment: `split <- lapply(list, function(x) split(x, ifelse(x$value >= threshold, 1, 2)))` Sorry, can't find the option to edit my comment.

Comment: You could also define the `value` parameter inside the function call with `function(list, filename, path, threshold, value)` to be even more dynamic in your use of the function.

Comment: I still don't understand why using filename parameter in your answer? I could use dir.create("~/") for setting path. Any chance to make the code more compatible ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. The `filename` and `path` parameters are in it so you can set different paths and name the output files without having to edit the function. You could add something like `if(!dir.exists(path)) (dir.create(path))` before the `mapply`-call, so you don't have to make sure the path already exists.

Comment: Of course you can delete the parameters and just write the path and filename directly into the function, but that leaves you with less choice when using it...

Comment: To use the function as it is presented in my answer, just use something like `ouput <- splitMe(dfList, filename = "discarded", path = "yourpath", threshold = 10)` and insert the path to the folder where you want your discarded data csv's to be saved as `yourpath`.

Comment: in your script, mapply takes two arguments, what second parameter is used for ? if I want to use this line : write.csv(., sprintf("discard.%s.csv", x), row.names = FALSE), instead of using mapply, any idea?

Comment: I used mapply to account for variable lengths of the list you put in. The second parameter `y` is just `1:length(list)` and manages the enumeration of the csv-files. You can probably use `sprintf()` instead of `paste0()`, but you cannot do it without a loop if you want your datasets in separate files. I don't think you can put all datasets in a single csv-file because of different lengths.